# import large XML to oracle DB

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I would like to play with [Stack Overflow's data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump) in Oracle. The format that they gave me is in XML and it is very very huge (one XML file is about 3GB). I would like to do an import of this data to my Oracle DB. I know one other guy in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998055/oracle-loading-a-large-xml-file) topic managed to work on it using the XML directly. Any ideas or suggestions to make this happen easily?

Comment: How do you want it in your Oracle database? A table with an XMLTYPE column? In relational format?

Comment: I want it in a relational format

Comment: And what's wrong with the method shown by Vincent Malgrat in that other thread?

Comment: I don't know how to put the xml into the directory...

Comment: You just place the xml file somewhere on your server, you remember the OS directory you've put it in and you define an Oracle directory object on that OS directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the groovy SQL and XML libraries--you should be able to get up and running pretty quick even with minimal Java/Groovy experience.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL

[Groovy XML](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper)

You'll need to install groovy and get the ojdbc14.jar drivers from Oracle.  Put your code in a file and run:

```
groovy -cp ojdbc14.jar myscript.groovy
```