# Access data from oracle 11g

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, kml

Here is my code snippet:
[Xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxmDt.png)

In this xml file , i want to get data in  tag from oracle 11g database.
Is there any way to do that??

Comment: Screen shots are not code snippets. Please post the actual XML in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are answers to similar questions already.

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982687/oracle-plsql-how-to-parse-xml-and-insert-into-table)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998055/oracle-loading-a-large-xml-file)