# xml to oracle DB table : encountering problems

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00933

I have a sample xml file created using Editplus( in windows).

```
  < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  < badges >
    < row UserId="3714" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.923"/>
    < row UserId="994" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957"/>
  < / badges>
```

My goal here is to get this information into Oracle DB table. As suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998055?sort=newest#sort-top, I tried to execute the sql commands. But couldn't succeed,

========================= sql query 1 ============================

```
SQL> SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('D', 'tmp.xml'), nls_charset_id('UTF8')) xml_data FROM dual;

  XML_DATA
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
  <badges>
     <row UserId="3714" Name
```

In the output, I see half of the xml file got truncated. And the encoding type in output is seen as WINDOWS-1252. Could someone explain why is it happening so?

==========================================================================

=============================== sql query 2 ===============================

```
SQL> SELECT UserId, Name, to_timestamp(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') dt

  2        FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('D', 'tmp.xml'), 
  3                             nls_charset_id('WINDOWS-1252')) xml_data
  4                FROM dual),
  5             XMLTable('for $i in /badges/row
  6                                  return $i'
  7                      passing xml_data
  8                      columns UserId NUMBER path '@UserId',
  9                              Name VARCHAR2(50) path '@Name',
 10                              dt VARCHAR2(25) path '@Date');
```

`XMLTable('for $i in /badges/row
               *
       ERROR at line 5:
       ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

=====================================================================
The same query was working here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998055?sort=newest#sort-top. But for me it doesn't. 
I have oracle 10g installed on my machine.
Could someone suggest the corrections to make the queries work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your first point, your output is only truncated on display. You can change how many bytes are displayed in SQL*Plus with `SET LONG`:

```
SQL> SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('D', 'test.xml'), 
  2         nls_charset_id('WINDOWS-1252')) xml_data FROM dual;

XML_DATA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<badges>
  <row UserId="3714" Name=

SQL> SET LONG 4000
SQL> /

XML_DATA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<badges>
  <row UserId="3714" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.923"/>
  <row UserId="994" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957"/>
</badges>
```

As you have noticed, your character set will be modified per your NLS session parameters (i-e: the file will be translated to the character set of your client).

For the second point:

- What version of SQL*Plus are you using ? It might be older than the database and not recognizing the synthax
- could you post the exact query as you typed it in SQL*Plus (Please use the CODE feature of SO)

because I can not reproduce with Oracle 10.2.0.3:

```
SQL> SELECT UserId, NAME, to_timestamp(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') dt
  2    FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('D', 'test.xml'),
  3                 nls_charset_id('WINDOWS-1252')) xml_data FROM dual),
  4         XMLTable('for $i in /badges/row
  5                             return $i'
  6                   passing xml_data columns UserId NUMBER path '@UserId',
  7                   NAME VARCHAR2(50) path '@Name',
  8                   dt VARCHAR2(25) path '@Date');

    USERID NAME      DT
---------- --------- ----------------------------
      3714 Teacher   15/09/08 08:55:03,923000000
       994 Teacher   15/09/08 08:55:03,957000000
```

**Update:** This XMLTable synthax must be a new feature of the 10gR2 (10.2.*) (needs confirmation)

You can however use another method of accessing XML Data(described in [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985894/oracle-pl-sql-loop-through-xmltype-nodes/985985#985985)):

```
SQL> SELECT extractvalue(column_value, '/row/@UserId') "userID",
  2         extractvalue(column_value, '/row/@Name') "Name",
  3         extractvalue(column_value, '/row/@Date') "Date"
  4    FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE(bfilename('D', 'tmp.xml'),
  5                     nls_charset_id('WINDOWS-1252')).extract('/badges/row'))) t;

userID  Name      Date
------- --------- ------------------------
3718    Teacher   2008-09-15T08:55:03.923
994     Teacher   2008-09-15T08:55:03.957
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, I was wondering why:

```
encoding="UTF-8"
```

changed to

```
encoding="WINDOWS-1250"
```

in my case (after loading).

Then I realised what Oracle does here: it converts the utf-8 encoded xml to the default character set of your database, in order to be able to store it. That's why it changes the value of 'encoding'. If the default character set of your databse is utf-8, then 'encodig' will not change.

If your xml *actually* has utf-8 encoded characters, then trying to load it in the database with `nls_charset_id('WINDOWS-1252')` will throw an error.

So to put it short: you should not worry about `encoding="UTF-8"` changing to `encoding="WINDOWS-1252"`, just ignore it - the database is doing its job.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. 'set Long 4000' fixed the truncation issue.

But I am still struggling to get the second query running. My sqlplus version is "SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.2.0". Do you think that version is the issue.

Here is the code i have tried.

```
SQL> select xmltype(bfilename('D','tmp.xml'),nls_charset_id('WINDOWS-1252')) xml_data from dual;

XML_DATA
-----------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<badges>
  <row UserId="3714" Name


SQL> set LONG 4000
SQL> /

XML_DATA
--------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<badges>
 <row UserId="3714" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.923"/>
 <row UserId="994" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957"/>
</badges>


SQL> SELECT UserId, NAME, to_timestamp(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') dt
2        FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('D', 'tmp.xml'),
3                     nls_charset_id('WINDOWS-1252')) xml_data FROM dual),
4             XMLTable('for $i in /badges/row
5                                 return $i'
6                       passing xml_data columns UserId NUMBER path '@UserId',
7                       NAME VARCHAR2(50) path '@Name',
8                       dt VARCHAR2(25) path '@Date');
       XMLTable('for $i in /badges/row
               *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: @Shafi: I added another method to access XML data in my answer. This method should work with Oracle 10gR1