# How to "Open" XML data in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, oracle, plsql

Here is an example of some TSQL that I would like to rewrite in PL/SQL.

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = '<theRange>
    <theRow><First>Bob</First><Last>Smith</Last><Age>30</Age></theRow>
    <theRow><First>Sue</First><Last>Jones</Last><Age>34</Age></theRow>
    <theRow><First>John</First><Last>Bates</Last><Age>40</Age></theRow>
</theRange>'

;WITH OpenedXML AS (
    SELECT  r.value('First[1]','varchar(50)') AS First,
        r.value('Last[1]','varchar(50)') AS Last,
        r.value('Age[1]','int') AS Age
    FROM @xml.nodes('//theRange/theRow') AS Row(r)
)
SELECT * 
FROM OpenedXML
WHERE Age BETWEEN 30 AND 35
```

Can anyone give me some direction here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a couple of methods are described in this SO:

[Oracle Pl/SQL: Loop through XMLTYPE nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985894/oracle-pl-sql-loop-through-xmltype-nodes)

**Update:** it's rather straightforward since both methods are pure SQL (you can call this SQL from PL/SQL or any tool that interacts with the DB):

```
SQL> WITH openedXml AS (
  2  SELECT extractvalue(column_value, '/theRow/First') FIRST,
  3         extractvalue(column_value, '/theRow/Last') LAST,
  4         to_number(extractvalue(column_value, '/theRow/Age')) Age
  5    FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE('<theRange>
  6      <theRow><First>Bob</First><Last>Smith</Last><Age>30</Age></theRow>
  7      <theRow><First>Sue</First><Last>Jones</Last><Age>34</Age></theRow>
  8      <theRow><First>John</First><Last>Bates</Last><Age>40</Age></theRow>
  9  </theRange>').extract('/theRange/theRow')))
 10  )
 11  SELECT *
 12    FROM openedxml
 13   WHERE age BETWEEN 30 AND 35;

FIRST     LAST       AGE
--------- -------- -----
Bob       Smith       30
Sue       Jones       34
```

Comment: Hi Vincent.  That was a good link (+1) but I don't know enough to see how the answers there solve my problem.  There are two responses.  One is a SQL Plus solution and the other is a PLSQL solution but it uses something called XMLTYPE without giving a complete answer.  If I knew more that would probably have solved it for me.

Comment: @wcm: I don't know much about SQL Server but in this example the synthax looks a lot like Oracle. nodes = XMLSequence + extract -- value = extractvalue

Comment: Ya have to understand that MS steals as much as possible from Oracle :o).  In TSQL you tend to split your solutions into different steps.  It seems that in Oracle you try to do everything in a single select.  In my code, I declare @xml as the XML data type and then I set the value and then I use the value in my select.  Your code creates the XMLTYPE explicitly in the body of the select.  The Oracle solution is probably more efficient but I think the TSQL is easier to read through and understand.  This was a great answer.  I wish I could up vote you more than once.